Google Picker popup window not loading - Django
I am using Google's documentation on the Google Picker at https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample and the popup for google drive is not opening when i use this code in django template. I authorize my gmail account but the popup is just not loading. It works fine when i run it via live server on a plain html ( so everything is setup good regarding API_KEY, CLIENT_ID and APP_ID ) but when i run the code inside django, the popup is not there. I tried 3 different (django) projects and the issue persists.
Google console is not showing any errors, nothing, it's blank.
I do see that APIs return 200 message, so i suspect something about Django is not working well. Cookies or whatever it can be, but i spent past several hours on this and can't find a solution

Finally found it.. It's required to add SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = 'same-origin-allow-popups' to settings.py. Credits to Sand1929 over there at github tread
